# Android Studio Media Player won't stop after orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-orientation

If I change the orientation of the phone the music would keep playing which is good but it won't pause or stop either.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_music);

    musicState = String.valueOf(player.getState());

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        musicState = savedInstanceState.getString("State");

    }

    player.state = MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.valueOf(musicState);

}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("Red", r);
    outState.putInt("Green", g);
    outState.putInt("Blue", b);
    outState.putFloat("SPEED", playbackspeed);
    outState.putInt("PROGRESS", progressUpdate);
    outState.putInt("Update", updateIncrement);
    outState.putInt("Duration", duration);
    outState.putString("State", musicState);

}


public void onMusicBackClick ( View v ) {
    Log. d (" g53mdp ", " button pressed !") ;


    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentMusic.this, MainActivity.class);
    player.stop();
    intent.putExtra("Red", r);
    intent.putExtra("Green", g);
    intent.putExtra("Blue", b);
    intent.putExtra("SPEED", playbackspeed);

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public void onPlayClick (View v)
{
    Log.d("MP3 Player", "Music Play button pressed");
    if(player.getState() == MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.PAUSED)
    {
        player.play();
        musicState = String.valueOf(player.getState());
    }
    else if(player.getState() == MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.PLAYING)
    {
        player.pause();
        musicState = String.valueOf(player.getState());
    }
    else
    {
        player.load(musicURL, playbackspeed);
        musicState = String.valueOf(player.getState());

        updateIncrement = player.getDuration()/100;
        duration = player.getDuration();
        musicProgress = findViewById(R.id.p_musicProgress);
        musicProgress.setMax(duration);

        progress = player.getProgress();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progress = player.getProgress();
                progressUpdate = progress;
                musicProgress.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }, 0, updateIncrement);
    }
}

public void onPauseClick (View v)
{
    Log.d("MP3 Player", "Music pause button pressed");
    if(player.getState() == MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.PLAYING)
    {
        player.pause();
    }
}
public void onStopClick (View v)
{
    Log.d("MP3 Player", "Music stop button pressed");
    if(player.getState() == MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.PAUSED || player.getState() == MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.PLAYING)
    {
        player.stop();
    }
    player.stop();
}
```

I thought just converting values to string and then extracting it and putting it back would work but if you play the media file and orientated the phone it almost goes rogue.

I'm printing out states and am checking every state under every single interaction and even after recreating the activity after orientation it says and tells me its actually stopped but its still some how playing?

Comment: Could you include the entire class?

Comment: Where is `player` declared? If it's a variable in the activity then when the activity is re-created the music keeps playing from the reference in the old instance's context, which is no longer accessible. Decouple your data from your activity lifcycle using a ViewModel and both this and your last question will be resolved as the data will persist between re-creation of the activity.

Comment: Its currently declared at the very top like so     MP3Player player = new MP3Player();

Comment: Would i not be able to pass the old state as a variable into save on instnace and recovery and reset it ?

Comment: No, it's not memory-safe that way. A ViewModel is the proper way to persist data through the activity lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the reference to the MP3 player instance is not persisting when the activity is recreated, but continues to exist in the background since it's playing music. The correct way to persist anything through the activity lifecycle is to use a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), you should create one and store your MP3 player instance there.